# Jquery onmouseover effects only specific div for similar elements

Tags: jquery, events, html

Currently I have this scenario

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="fade-title">...content...</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <div class="fade-title">...content...</div>
</div>
```

When I move my mouse to one of the div boxes, I only want the corresponding `fade-title` to disappear, not all off them. Is there any way around this?

Apparently `$(this).$('.fade-title').hide()` (I know this will still close ALL of the fade-title) or `$(this:last-child).hide()` (since fade-title will always be the last child of the box div) works.

Comment: `$('.fade-title', this).hide()`

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
$(".fade-title", $(this)).hide()
```

or

```
$(this).children(".fade-title").hide()
```

$(this).$(...) is not valid

Answer (score 0):

use `find()`;

```
$(this).find('.fade-title').hide();
```

or `children()`;

```
$(this).children('.fade-title').hide();
```

or using context

```
$('.fade-title', this).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one, like this? http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/6StSA/2/

## JQUERY

```
$('.box').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).find('.fade-title').hide();
}).mouseout(function(){
  // if you dont want to show back again, comment below script 
  $(this).find('.fade-title').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/60/

Script:

```
$('.box').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('.fade-title').hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box" style='height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red;'>
   <div class="fade-title">...content... 1</div>
</div>

<div class="box" style='height:100px; width:100px; background-color:green;'>
   <div class="fade-title">...content... 2</div>
</div>
```